# Extract one column top n values as one length character in R

Tags: r

Given a dataframe as follows, how could we get `feature` column's top `n` (let's say `n=5` at this case) values and convert to one length character?

```
    X.IncMSE  IncNodePurity feature
14  17.047198   16538.30890 RMFSL
16  11.098980   8696.06086  BORROW
2   8.088110    4995.53967  BAA10YM
24  5.847918    1883.49994  DTTHFM
25  5.487581    1277.76421  DTRTM
27  5.171936    1190.90316  IPCONGD
3   4.864875    2822.91257  AAA10YM
11  4.783012    333.98030   TWEXBMTH
34  4.617952    1285.28342  HOUST
10  4.562884    319.38383   MPRIME
```

My exepcted result will like: `"TERMCBAUTO48NS, BAA10YM, AAA10YM, TB3SMFFM, T5YFFM"`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The expected result you are showing is not actually a list, rather a vector. Is `df$feature[1:5]` what you are looking for? By the way, you called it a list because you come from Python, am I correct?

Comment: Also `head(dat$feature, 5L)`

Comment: Do you mean `df$feature[1:5]`?

Comment: Kind of, but not exactly I needed. With your code I get: `[1] "TERMCBAUTO48NS" "BAA10YM" [3] "AAA10YM" "TB3SMFFM" [5] "T5YFFM" `. Btw, I modified the expected result.

Comment: Do you need the commas between the values of the column `feature`? Otherwise what you are obtaining is a vector

Comment: Not really necessary, but if it has commas, it's ok.

Comment: Does this give your expected output? `paste(df$feature[1:5], collapse = ", ")`

Comment: @ahbon I add it as an answer so you can upvote and accept it, thanks :)

Comment: @ahbon I would recommend reading up on data structures in R before opening more of these questions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the expected output:

```
paste(df$feature[1:5], collapse = ", ")
```

---

#### EDIT

The `paste` function concatenates objects after converting them to `character` class. If a vector is composed by more than one element, the argument `collapse` concatenates the elements using the passed string as separator.

Example:

```
v <- LETTERS[1:5]
v
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
paste(v, collapse = ", ")
# [1] "A, B, C, D, E"
```

The object `v` is a character vector of five elements. The output given after using `paste` with the argument `collapse` is a vector of one element.

For more information I suggest you to read the documentation with `?paste`

Comment: Could you explain the function of `paste` in your solution pls?

Comment: This is not a list, but a character of length one - either this doesn't answer the question or the question is unclear, please clarify @ahbon

Comment: Thanks, I'll modify the title and content of my question.